# iReport add/modify variable dialog

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, ireport

This is very dumb - but I've seen all the tutorials and guides - and my version (iReport 3.6.0) of iReport does not seem to match what I'm seeing.

I need to create a new variable and use the add/modify variable dialog to format my variable - and to enter the conditions for it (Variable Expression).

I've spent the better part of a day trying to find this dialog - no luck.

I can add a variable via Report Designer. I see no option to do anything further than this.

The odds are long on finding an answer here - but the odds are better than I currently have. ;)

Thank you.

Scott in Maine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Finally!

Highlight the Variable and go to Properties.

Not obvious AT ALL!